# Handling exceptions coming from a class

Tags: php

I'm trying to get values from a MySQL database and I'm using a class from github (https://github.com/lincanbin/PHP-PDO-MySQL-Class) which is handling exeptions within the class.

The problem is if I try to do a select from a table that doesn't exist, I'm getting an error from the object saying its a fault. I realize it's bad to select from a table that doesn't exists, but I want to override that message and outputting my own error message. I also want the class intact as it is provided from the developer, how can I do that?

If I try something like this:

```
try {
$db = new Db(..., ..., ..., ..., ...);
$db->query("select * from missingtable");
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo "my error";
}
```

it doesn't print the string "my error", because the class that runs the query-method have this code:

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->ExceptionLog($e, $this->BuildParams($query), 'Init', array('query' => $query, 'parameters' => $parameters));
            return false;

        }
```

where the method ExceptionLog includes this:

```
$message = $e->getMessage();
$exception = 'Unhandled Exception. <br />';
...
if (($this->pdo === null || !$this->inTransaction()) && php_sapi_name() !== "cli") {
            //Prevent search engines to crawl
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            header("Status: 500 Internal Server Error");
            echo $exception;
            exit();
        } else {
            throw $e;
        }
```

Can I somehow catch the error again outside of this class? Or what would be the best practice in this scenario? Should I edit this class for my own usage or can I handle the object from this class better?

Update:
The easiest solution I could think of is to replace

```
echo $exception;
```

into

```
throw new Exception("my error");
```

in the last snippet. But is there a better solution to handle it outside the class?

Comment: _"Can I somehow catch the error again outside of this class?"_ - if the `ExceptionLog` method goes into the if-branch, then you can't do _anything_ after that, because it ends all script execution via `exit`.

Comment: Your right. So basically the class wasn't written in a best-practice way? Thank you for your reply. Please write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: This class is specifically designed to make you application crash on errors and expose potentially sensitive details to the internet. Most of the affected methods are private so you can't extend it. It'd be much easier to just cherry-pick the two relevant features it really offers (iterator and list binding) into your own brand new class.